# How to change the background colour of a toolbar in ExtJS4

Tags: extjs, background, extjs4, toolbar

I am trying to change the background color of a toolbar. Right now, I am having ext-classic theme. I want toolbar background color to be dark blue, but this color change should NOT be applicable for all the toolbar's being created. Can someone guide me on how I can do this particular thing?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: use cls config of toolbar and set the background in css: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.toolbar.Toolbar-cfg-cls

Comment: Thanks @newmount can u please provide me some reference on how exactly that has to be done..because I am not familiar with using cls config

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also can try using ["style"](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Component-cfg-style) config option.

```
Ext.define 'App.your_package.CustomToolbar',
    extend: 'Ext.toolbar.Toolbar'
    xtype: 'my-custom-toolbar'
    style: 'background-color: #112D41;'
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

use cls config

```
Ext.create('Ext.toolbar.Toolbar', {
    ...,
    cls: 'myBgCls',
    ...
```

and then css to change background:

```
.myBgCls{
    background: blue;
}
```